# Method of creating verticies around object in photo based on background color

Tags: objects, image

Similar to how you would select the outline of an object based on a common background color in a 2d graphics program and then delete the background, is there a way in Blender to import a reference photo and create vertices automatically based on where the object in an image meets the background color. For example, making the vertices that would create the outline of the lettuce leaf in the image below:
[image: picture of lettuce leaf]

Comment: What about using a vector program to trace it then import svg curves into blender?

Comment: +brandon-bien Thanks, that actually works better than I expected. I can even use GIMP to do an auto select, make that selection a path, then export it as SVG and import into Blender pretty quickly.

Comment: Glad that helped, don't forget that inkscape has a trace bitmap function under path that will do a simliar thing.